# VSIX. Add code to existing class

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I created vsix extension which have my custom templates. These templates create custom classes. After that I created a template that should write the pieces of code into another existing class (to supplement it), but in the end it overwrites it. I was looking for an answer on the Internet, but I did not find anything (maybe I was looking for information badly). So, the question is: Is there any opportunity to create vsix with such template and if it's possible how can I do this?

I will be glad for any help!

Comment: If you are looking to write code to existing template, wouldn't Code Snippets be better choice. You could pack it along VSIX as well.

Comment: Anu Viswan, Thank you for advice! I will try to do it this way, but it would be better to automate it because my extension create dictionaries by custom templates and all of them are the same, just with different names. But yes, code snippets are also the good choice, it will save me a little time.

Comment: @keeroll, Code snippets would be a nice answer if you want to add code to existing class, if this issue has been resolved, you could share your solution as an answer and mark it. Have a nice day:)